# IEEEtran remove author picture

Tags: graphics, bibliographies, lyx, ieeetran

I'm using LyX and the `article (IEEEtran)` template to write a paper for an IEEE conference.

In the biographies section, there's a default space for a picture for the first author. Even if I remove the optional placeholder in the LyX GUI, There's an empty box generated in the PDF where such a picture would go.

I know  that I can get around this with LaTeX directly by using `\begin{IEEEbiographynophoto}` instead of `\begin{IEEEbiography}`.
However, I do not see a way to get around this without having to export to LaTeX from LyX and then edit the `.tex` file. Is there a way to get LyX to not require a picture for the first author?

Comment: Your question looks `Lyx` Related ? You don't want to resolve using IEEEtran custom LaTeX environment ? right

Comment: @texenthusiast: You are correct. I would prefer to do this with LyX functions, without having to write any custom LaTeX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make the `IEEEbiography` react just like the `IEEEbiographynophoto` environment by placing the following in your LaTeX preamble:

```
\renewenvironment{IEEEbiography}[1]
  {\IEEEbiographynophoto{#1}}
  {\endIEEEbiographynophoto}
```

[image: LaTeX Preamble]