# How to best make a biography with photo

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

[image]I want to add my ID photo at the right of the biography because I used an article with two columns . How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try the `strip` environment from the `cuted` package.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand what you want to do. Can you explain again what you have and what you want to do. A solution will in all likeliness depend on your document class, the exact way you produce your two-column format and your bibliography. It would greatly help if you could show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you have so far (follow the [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) to find out how to produce an MWE).

Comment: Any news here? As I wrote in my comment above I don't quite understand what you want to do. But even if someone else understands what you want to do it will still be quite difficult for them to come up with an answer that works for you not knowing how you obtain your bibliography and your two-column layout. Please show us an MWE of what you have so far ([I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)). If the questions stays as is and is not edited in due time, I will vote to close as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Hello! I have to write an article with two columns, ok! at the end,  I must to add the Biography of Authers.  The Problem is following :

Comment: when I introduce the application of biography with photo, the emplacement ressort on the left of the paper... !,It became confused with the second column. can you help me please to get the photo inside of the body of biography text, on the left or on the right does't matter. The most important that it did not get above another part of the text above an other column (because I have two columns, I have'nt the freedom to put my photo anywhere ) Thank's a lot for your response; best regards

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. It would definitely help me to see an example of your code that shows us what you are doing, see [https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Without it I don't see any way I could help you.

Comment: \begin{IEEEbiography}

Comment: \begin{Ieeeniography}Farida Boulaghmen{c:\users\Asus\Desktop\F.Boulaghmen photo\png/}}{F.Boulaghmen has completed her Phd at ......\end{IEEEbiography}

Comment: can you please give me an email in order to send you a capture photo about the probleml

Comment: Please add the full example code to your question. You should do that by pressing the edit button. You can also upload an image there.

Comment: @FaridaBOULAGHMEN Please read the link: [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you could share a *reduced* version of the code in text form so we can copy and paste it. Very few people will be happy to copy the code from a screenshot and the screenshot does not contain all the necessary information.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130847/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45010/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100798/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277919/35864 https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10026 can help you

Comment: thank's a lot for your help. I tried to build a mwe in order to explain the problem but it put "too long of number of caracters !!" the picture which I sent is clear

Comment: I can not follow you suggestion ( tex.stackexchange.com/q/130847/35864) beacause I obtained the picture at the right and it confused with the other column

Comment: The idea of an MWE is to reduce the problem so much that it fits well within the character limits enforced on this site. You do not need to put up your entire paper here, just as much as necessary to reproduce the problem. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. For the MWE you can probably delete the entire text body (if necessary leave in a bit of filler text) and place only a few dummy entries in the bibliography. The picture gives us some hints, but it shows far to little of your document to give good help.

Comment: all your suggestions are interresting but I am  beginer of the Latex's uses and the deadline is became near

Comment: look in the picture  2 what I obtained in using :"tex.stackexchange.com/q/45010/35864"

Comment: Could you solve your problem with the help of my answer below?

Answer (score 6):

The following works for me. See also [Displaying Bibliography Photo in IEEE Journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130847/35864) and the [IEEEtran documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf).

The environment `IEEEbiography` takes an optional argument (in square brackets) with a command that provides the picture and a mandatory argument (in curly braces) that takes the name.

```
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}}]{Prof.\ van Duck}
<Your text here>
\end{IEEEbiography}
```

Note that the picture argument must be wrapped in curly braces since it contains square brackets itself. In the above `example-image-duck` should be replaced with the path to the photo. The measurements are taken from the [IEEEtran documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf).

The environment `IEEEbiographynophoto` does not have an optional argument and does not show a picture.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\nocite{IEEEexample:book,IEEEexample:incollectionmanyauthors,
  IEEEexample:confwithvolume,IEEEexample:techrepstdsub,IEEEexample:article_typical,
  IEEEexample:articleetal,IEEEexample:conf_typical,IEEEexample:book_typical,
  IEEEexample:articlelargepages,IEEEexample:articledualmonths,IEEEexample:bookwitheditor,
  IEEEexample:inbook}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,IEEEexample}

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}}]{Prof.\ van Duck}
Prof.\ van Duck is an esteemed scientist at the University of Quackland. \lipsum[1]
\end{IEEEbiography}

\begin{IEEEbiographynophoto}{Prof.\ Quack}
Prof.\ van Quack is an esteemed scientist at the University of Quackland, but she does not get a picture. \lipsum[1]
\end{IEEEbiographynophoto}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the author name!

Comment: +1 Prof. van Duck is very pleased to be esteemed <3<3<3

Comment: what happens if its not IEEEtran?

Comment: @Exploring Then it is a different matter altogether. The environments used here are defined in `IEEEtran`. If you are not using that, what is available for you is anyone's guess. Please ask a new question and give as much detail about your setup as possible.